# React native modal screen change

Tags: react-native

I have a full screen modal and I want to "navigate" inside modal.
The structure of the modal
is a header and a footer that is the same in all screens and the body that is the different screens. Body is the only that will change.
How can achieve this with React Native **Functional component** without dependencies.

[image]

Comment: Stack navigator is what you need

Comment: No, nothing to do with it, I think you didn't understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create :

- A state React.useState step initialise at 0
- An array of object with what you want for "body" elements
- A function next and / or back to update state step change body

You can get elements of your body like so :

```
steps[activeStep].label
```

You have a good example from here demo [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qf4f31?file=/demo.tsx) and here documentation [material ui stepper](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/)